# ImportError in GAMS Python API

Tags: python, api, gams-math

I have just installed GAMS Python API on my macOS. However, whenever I run "import gamstransfer as gt" vscode throws this error:

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_gams2numpy.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_gams2numpy.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))

How to fix this error?

Comment: You installed the wrong version of the library.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable about this stuff.  Could you please tell me which version should I use?

Comment: Use the arm64e version instead of the x86_64 version as described in the error message.